# delete previous character in a byte array

Tags: algorithm

Given a byte array, in which characters can be 1 byte or 2 bytes long 
For 1-byte characters, the Most significant bit must be 0. For a 2- 
byte character, the most significant bit of the most significant byte 
must be one and the most significant bit of the least significant byte 
is don’t care (X). You are given the index, I of a character in the 
byte array. Note that I-1 or I+1 can lead you to either a character or 
the middle of a character. Give a logic (no need of code) to delete 
the previous character of the one to which I points.

Comment: So you want us to solve your homework for you? What have you tried so far? What didn't work? Why didn't it work?

Comment: @darhuuk think twice before marking any question as homework..this is a discussion forum not your personnel blog..mind it

Comment: Ohhh my god - where are such no-brainers given as homework?

Comment: @prp Bremen, by any chance? Grundschule or Volkshochschule?

Comment: @Dante that is concern for me too..in problem also it is stated that previous or following character can be an independent character or may not be..

Comment: So, I'm wondering if any of the answers give a working solution?

Comment: the last solution discussed here seems to work http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?interview.11.334807.4 i couldn't find any loophole in that solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well then, let's try. I'm assuming the array starts at index = 0 and that we know its size. If not, change the while loop in the code below to count down and jiggle the logic around a bit.

The real question is not how to remove the previous element. It's figuring out if the given index i is the start of a char (be it 1- or 2-byte) or the middle of a 2-byte one. Once we know that, removing the previous element is trivial, since it's trivial to figure out if the previous element is 1- or 2-byte.

So, I believe this should work to figure out what index i is. Pseudo-code:

```
if MSB_i == 0
{
  if MSB_(i+1) == 1
    -> Start of 2-byte char
  else
    -> Start of 1-byte char
} else
{
  if MSB_(i+1) == 0
    -> Middle of 2-byte char
  else
  {
    j = i + 1
    while (MSB_j == 1) AND (j != size)
      j++

    j = j - i
    if j modulo 2 == 1
      -> Start of 2-byte char
    else
      -> Middle of 2-byte char
}
```

Obviously, I have not implemented and check this, but it seems like all options are covered. Feel free to correct me or poke me if you want a written explanation as to why this should work.

Comment: what have you considered about Don'care condition.i think it can be both o or 1.if that is the case then your first case can not guranteed to be true..

Comment: @prp First case: MSB_i == 0, so either it is a 1-byte char or the start of a 2-byte char. To check, we check the MSB of the next byte. If it is 0, the one pointed to by i must be a 1-byte char. If it is 1, this means the byte pointed to by i must be the start of a 2-byte char. Hence, my first case takes care of the don't care.

Answer (score 0):

For any element `array[i]`, you can determine if `i` points to a single byte character, the start of a 2-byte character, or the middle of a 2-byte character using the following test:

Starting with `array[i-1]` count the number of contiguous MSB==1.

If `array[i]` is preceded by an ODD number of 1's, then `array[i]` is the middle of a 2-byte array.

If `array[i]` is preceded by an EVEN number of 1's, then if `MSB(array[i])` is 0, `array[i]` is a single byte character, otherwise `array[i]` is the start of a 2-byte character.

Since we're trying to delete the character just before `array[i]`, once you determine if `array[i]` is the start or the middle of a character, then you have to run the same test for `array[i-x]`, where `x` is either 1 or 2 depending on if `array[i]` is pointing to the start or middle of a character, respectively.

---

Edit (What happens when arr[0] is 1-byte, and arr[1] is 2-byte?):

Firstly, more detail about the search for contiguous 1's: When counting contiguous 1's, the loop stops if we reach array[0], or MSB(array[j])==0.

```
odd=0
j = i
while( j && MSB(arr[j-1]) )
    j-=1
    odd^=1       <<(binary XOR)
```

When the loop completes, odd will be 1 if there are an odd number of contiguous 1's and odd will be 0 if there are 0 or an even number of contiguous 1's.

---

If we have an array with a 1-byte character in arr[0] and a 2-byte character in arr[1], then, supposedly, i can only have the values 0, 1, or 2.

- i=0:  The loop never runs because i==0. We consider there to be an **EVEN** number of preceding 1's because odd==0. The MSB of arr[i] is 0, so **arr[i] is the start of a 1-byte character**.
- i=1:  The loop never runs because MSB(arr[i-1]) is 0. We consider there to be an **EVEN** number of contiguous 1's because odd==0.  The MSB of arr[i] is 1, so **arr[i] is the start of a 2-byte character**.
- i=2:  The loop runs one time.  We find an **ODD** number of consecutive 1's.  Because there is an odd number of preceding 1's, **arr[i] is the middle of a 2-byte character**.

Comment: if we have an array with following arrangment then how ur algo will work arr[0] = 1 byte arr[1] = 2 byte

Comment: @prp: My previous description does not test for i==0, or near 0.  As you're counting down, you'll need to account for that.  I'll edit my answer to provide an explanation for your example...

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you all are a bit confused?

First, what is "the middle of a 2 byte character"? Is it perhaps the last 1/3 of the first character and the first 1/3 of the second one? No, its nonsense. A 2 byte character has a first and a second byte, but no "middle".

Second, because it is not specified in what order the most significant and least significant bytes are stored, the exercise is a bit underspecified.

But let us assume, that the LSByte is stored at the lower address then the task is easy. Just check the most significant bit of byte[i-1], if it is set, then the previous character is a double byte character, else it's single byte. (We know that i adresses a character, not just a byte.)

Comment: ok whatever you have considered is correct about the problem but your solution is not correct..say we have MSB of arr[i]=0 and arr[i-1] =1,then if you want to delete previous character then you have to move i-2 because for arr[i-1]=1 is current character and you have to delete previous character ..hope you understand ...

Comment: No, the MS bit of arr[i] is irrelevant in both cases. The char at i is either single byte or i points at the low byte (if the byte order is low byte, high byte)